# RecyclerView scrolls down when expanding item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which displays list items. These items expand when the user clicks them. The show animation works fine but every time an item gets clicked, the `RecyclerView` seems to add an item at the very top position but then hides it so that it scrolls down as you can see in the GIF below.

[image: RecyclerView scrolls up GIF]

My list item layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txv_item_history_bill_type"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv_item_history_bill_type">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imv_item_history_category"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txv_item_history_bill_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:letterSpacing="0.15"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imv_item_history_category"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txv_item_history_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:letterSpacing="0"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccentTextColor"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imv_item_history_category"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv_item_history_bill_type" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txv_item_history_date_amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:letterSpacing="0.1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imv_item_history_category"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txv_item_history_description" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_item_history_bill_action_buttons_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_history_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_edit"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" />

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_history_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_delete" />

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_edit_amount"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"/>

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_edit_description"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"/>

        <android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_change_category"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_item_history_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
    android:background="@color/colorDivider" />
```

Code for expantion:

```
    final boolean isExpanded = position == mExpandedPosition;
    holder.mLlBillActionButtonsContainer.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1 : position;
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is happening due to the combination of these two lines in your code:

> ```
> TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView);
> notifyDataSetChanged();
> ```

RecyclerView supports animations by default, as long as you use the more-specific "notify" methods (like `notifyItemChanged()`) instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`. So, if you can use those instead, you can delete the `TransitionManager` call.

The good news is that you know which position was "expanded" before, so you can call `notifyItemChanged()` on only the old position and the new position. This should get you much better animations.

Here's an updated listener for you:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    int previousExpandedPosition = mExpandedPosition;
    mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1 : position;

    if (previousExpandedPosition != -1) {
        notifyItemChanged(previousExpandedPosition);
    }
    if (mExpandedPosition != -1) {
        notifyItemChanged(mExpandedPosition);
    }
});
```